# php insert value to column not working

Tags: php, mysql

Here i am trying to insert the value to mysql table column,i have assigned a string value to variable and i am using that variable to insert value to mysql table column.

```
$userrrole = "vendor";
                $query_new_user_insert = $this->db_connection->prepare('INSERT INTO users (user_name, user_password_hash, user_email, user_activation_hash, user_registration_ip, user_role, user_registration_datetime) VALUES(:user_name, :user_password_hash, :user_email, :user_activation_hash, :user_registration_ip, :user_registration_ip, :user_role, now())');
                $query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':user_name', $user_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':user_password_hash', $user_password_hash, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':user_role', $userrrole, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

The problem here is that i am able to insert all other values other than `:user_role`. when i run this query i am not able to insert value of :user_role instead the value is replaced by default value specified in mysql  setting.

how can i do this? how can i insert value of `:user_role`

Comment: check for errors on both PHP and MySQL/PDO. This is probaby failing you `$userrrole` and seems to be a typo. Should probably/most likely be `$userrole` or `$user_role` an error reporting will tell you that.

Comment: What is the datatype of the column `user_role` ??

Comment: I think variable userrole is spelled wrong. it should be $userrole and not $userrrole.
Not sure if am right. But try changing your varable name to $user_role

Comment: Tell you what. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. If it throws you an undefined variable userrrole notice, you'll know what to go after. Tell me if I'm right on this one ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You're using `:user_registration_ip` twice.
Fix the query as

```
INSERT INTO users (user_name, user_password_hash, user_email,
                   user_activation_hash, user_registration_ip,
                   user_role, user_registration_datetime)
           VALUES (:user_name, :user_password_hash, :user_email,
                   :user_activation_hash, :user_registration_ip,
                   :user_role, now())
```

Comment: Just about to say the same thing but yours came up while i was typing it.

Comment: Good catch. And also the fact that there may be a typo for their `$userrrole` variable. Seems a lot of r's, wouldn't you agree? ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I believe he should be using some good IDE, that'll show a warning for undefined variable. :-P

Comment: Error reporting will tell them that http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php ;-)